# CSS background image will display locally but not on gh-pages, receive 404 error

Tags: html, css, git, background-image, github-pages

Recently I was attempting to update my portfolio by adding a background image to the 'intro' class below.  I added the image through CSS and when opening my portfolio locally in Chrome the image was displayed correctly.  However, after committing my changes and then pushing up to my gh-pages the background image no longer displays.  Instead I am left with:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://jlquaccia.github.io/jq-design/img/swirl_pattern.jpg
```

Can someone please help?  I feel I have done this before without hitting any problems..  I'm also assuming that this should be an easy fix.  My code is below:

HTML

```
<section class="intro">
        <h1 class="intro-title">{ Hello, I'm Jason Quaccia. <br> an aspiring Bay Area based Front-end Web <span class"dev-design">Developer</span> &#38; <span class"dev-design">Designer</span> }</h1>
        <div class="down-arrow">
            <a href="#about"><img class="down-arrow" src="./IMG/arrow-203-32.png" alt="Down Arrow"></a>
        </div>
    </section>
```

CSS

```
.intro {
    height: 35em;
    background: url(../img/swirl_pattern.jpg);
}
```

Comment: The url it says your image is located here: http://www.jlquaccia.github.io/jq-design/img/swirl_pattern.jpg, but it's not, is it?

Comment: Correct, the folder I had my images in was actually called "IMG" and not "img".  So it was a case sensitive typo on my part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL is case sensitive, you are pointing to: http://jlquaccia.github.io/jq-design/img/swirl_pattern.jpg but you should be pointing to http://jlquaccia.github.io/jq-design/IMG/swirl_pattern.jpg instead (notice the IMG in uppercase)

So your CSS should be like this:

```
.intro {
    height: 35em;
    background: url(../IMG/swirl_pattern.jpg);
}
```

(Notice how you are doing it right for the arrow)

Comment: Thanks Alvaro!  I noticed the case sensitive part as well as I was digging deeper into things last night.  However, I didn't know that that would effect things.  Good to know.